# Is there a way to limit CSS styling for a link to a <p> / paragraph?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, reddit, paragraph

Currently i'm trying to overhaul a reddit page and i'm struggling to style multiple links in the sidebar. Is it possible to style links in a paragraph without a class? If not are there any other possibilities as i can't seem to find any except having multiple images.

```html
<p>
<a href="#">Only links in this paragraph will be styled.</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _"limit styling of a link to a paragraph"_ ... like only style links nested in paragraphs? Your question is unclear. Anyways if you want help you should share what you have attempted that isn't working.

Comment: That's exactly what i mean, an example is in the edited post. As for the CSS i don't know if it is possible to actually style only links nested in a paragraph or only the paragraph itself. As reddit only allows you to edit the CSS i can't make a class and style it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
p a {
  color: red;
}
```

You might need to add an `!important` to the properties you are trying to override.

Comment: Yes, i just noticed i'm a potato and noticed the other links are also in the same paragraph. This means they are all styled instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

### Basically, there are a few answers to this. I am going to order them I what I think would be most important to you.

---

**Way #1:**
*If you want to limit the styling to a specific paragraph you need to give the paragraph an ID or a CLASS.  Here is an example below.*

```
<p id="myParagraph">
     <a href="#">Link</a>
</p>
```

Then in your CSS you must "select" your paragraph and the tag you want.  You can do that like this...

```
p#myParagraph a {
     /* Style elements */
}
```

*Please note that you would put your ID after the pound sign and not necessarily "myParagraph"*

---

**Way #2:**
*You could just call the **Paragraph** tag and then the **Anchor** tag*

```
p a {
     /* Style Elements */
}
```